# Header fixed with border - the border should only shown by scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have coded my index.html with bootstra4 and have the header with border and the class sticky. I want the border only shown when the page is scrolled.

HTML

```
    <!-- TOP NAV -->
    <header id="topNav">
        <div class="container">
      .....

</div>
```

CSS

```
#header.shadow-after-3:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    bottom: -60px;
    background-image: url(../images/misc/shadow3.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

JS

The code of my js will not insert here - if it is nessasary i will try it again

Comment: Can you provide a link on codepen or smth we can check this live?

Comment: I try it....of couse i can upload it to my domain and provide a link....will this help also?

Comment: I hope so. Send me a link and I'll take a look.

Comment: @ Andrew Savetchuk the link to the upload is [link](https://knuddlwoelkchen.de/) - when you send me a mail (I'm using stackoberflow not so often) i can grand you ftp-access if this will help you

Comment: please, check out my reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the **box-shadow** attribute from **#header**:

Should be like this:

```
    #header {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 1px solid;
        -webkit-transition: all .800s;
        -moz-transition: all .800s;
        -o-transition: all .800s;
        transition: all .800s;
    }
```

2. Then change **border-bottom** attribute in **#header.transparent** to `border-bottom: none;`

Should be like this:

```
#header.transparent {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

3. Lastly, find and replace `#header.shadow-after-3:before` to `#header.fixed.shadow-after-3:before` in your CSS.

When the page is scrolled it adds the `fixed` class to header element that's why we should style this class.

Comment: I've tried it but nothing changed....but i thank you for spending your time for my problem :-)

For the next time i will just work without the shadow-class

Comment: @webtroll so you want to hide white border or shadow only?

Comment: only the border should hidden when the page is top  (the img shadow3.png) / class .shadow-after-3 should hidden when the page is top

Comment: it looks great - will the shadow shown /appears by scolling?

Comment: @webtroll yes, it appears by scrolling. I'll update the answer in 1 min

Comment: great - i take my dinner than i take a look :-)

You have also time to update the code :-)

Comment: @webtroll Take your time. I just updated the answer :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

With `Javascript` you can solve it easily.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250){  
        $('header').addClass("borderClass");
    }
    else{
        $('header').removeClass("borderClass");
    }
});
```